# How to speed up sending file using smtp

Tags: python, performance, smtp

I'm setting up a program which takes a screen shot of the screen and sends it to my email and I want to speed up the process since it will be taking more than one screenshot in a second and sending it to my email but because of the long process of verifying it breaks my program itself and cause lag.

I have tried to separate the log in process and sending process placing it outside of the function but it didn't send the email. I am wondering how I should structure it.

def sendingemail(filename):
    # creates SMTP session
    sendss = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

```
# start TLS for security
sendss.starttls()
email = '___@gmail.com'
password = 'password'


email = 'name@gmail.com'
password = 'pass'
send_to_email = 'pass@gmail.com'
subject = 'Person on Cam 1'
message = 'Person sighted'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = send_to_email
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

attachment = open(filename, 'rb') 

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet_stream')

part.set_payload((attachment).read())


encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= "+filename) 

msg.attach(part) 
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

It sends the email but its slow. I want to reduce the amount of time it wastes sending one email.

Comment: The lag is almost certainly due to your available upstream bandwidth, not the code itself. The best you can do is fork a new process to send the mail after you take the screen shot, but then you are just going to have a bunch of processes piling up in the background, because you simply cannot send the pictures faster than you can generate them.

Comment: @chepner But it also that it has to connect to the smtp over and over again. Once I get that fixed I'm going to lower the amount of time it's called.

Answer (score 1):

## Use one SMTP session to send many emails

You may keep open smtp session (reuse `server` object) and use it to send multiple email messages.

SMTP servers use `RSET` (reset) command before sendind "not first" email to check that SMTP session may be reused.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

> Low-level methods corresponding to the standard SMTP/ESMTP commands HELP, RSET, NOOP, MAIL, RCPT, and DATA are also supported. Normally these do not need to be called directly, so they are not documented here. For details, consult the module code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your provider, SMTP connection timesout after some seconds.
You can use the noop command to test connection status and catch the error (in case of a timeout error) and then call a reconnect function in the Exception.

A simple code to test how long a before a connection timesout:

```
import smtplib
import time

def login():
   global server

   username = 'user@domain.org'
   password = 'password'


   server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mail.domain.org", 465)
   logged = server.login(username, password)

   print('logded in:', logged, '\n')
   return logged

for i in range(30):
  def test_conn_open():
     try:
        stat = server.noop()[0]
        #Do anything for example send mail
        #server.sendmail(username, dest_mail, fullmessage)
     except:  
        stat = -1
        login() # login again if timeout happens
        test_conn_open()  #Ensures mail is sent on the current loop even if timeout happens
   
    print(stat, " ", i + 1)
    return True if stat == 250 else False

  r = test_conn_open()
  print(r)
  time.sleep(1)
```